# Swift SQLite query not returning any results

Tags: swift, sqlite

I have a database storing some data about TV series and am trying to retrieve the list of all the series names. I am using:

```
        var seriesNames: [String] = [String]()

        // Select query
        let findQueryString = "SELECT Name FROM Series"

        // Statement pointer
        var findStmt:OpaquePointer?

        // Preparing query
        if sqlite3_prepare(db, findQueryString, -1, &findStmt, nil) != SQLITE_OK{
            let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
            print("Error preparing series selection: \(errmsg)")
            return
        }

        while(sqlite3_step(findStmt) == SQLITE_ROW){
            seriesNames.append(String(cString: sqlite3_column_text(findStmt, 0)))
        }
```

However, there are never any results but running the same query in SQLiteBrowser confirms that there should be. This exact code was working earlier but seems to now have stopped working. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you 100% absolutely sure your program and this sqlitebrowser are using the same database file?

Comment: @Shawn I feel really dumb now! I completely forgot that running the program on my own device instead of an emulator would use a a different database!